# Redirect to specific page if any model (from various) is not authenticated with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using `Rails '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'` and I have different models **Organizer** and. **Sponsor** managed by `Devise 4.2`.

What I want is: ***If the user is not authenticated***, redirect to a specific view so they can click on their profile type and so redirect to the corresponding login form.

Actually I'm using [`devise_group`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers/ClassMethods:devise_group) feature to manage both models as a generic when needed.

My files are like this:

**application_ontroller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception

    devise_group :member, contains: [:organizer, :sponsor]

    private

    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        case resource
        when Organizer
            dashboard_path
        when Sponsor
            brochures_path
        end
    end
end
```

**brochures_controller.rb**

```
class BrochuresController < ApplicationController
    # Ensure an organizer is logged in before going ahead.
    before_action :authenticate_member!
end
```

Everything seemed to work fine but when I access any method in **BrochuresController** I was always redirected to the **organizers login form** which is nasty because the sponsor could get confused.

> - First Solution

I found a method to redirect to a neutral page where the user can select his profile so I added to the `ApplicationController`.

```
def authenticate_member!
    if member_signed_in?
        super
    else
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "Select your profile to login!"
    end
end
```

And it works fine when login in with Organizer.

> - New error

When I login with Sponsor I got this error:

```
super: no superclass method `authenticate_member!' for #<BrochuresController:0x007fa760e387f8> Did you mean? authenticate_sponsor!

Extracted source (around line #13):
11  def authenticate_member!
12      if member_signed_in?
13          super
14      else
15          redirect_to root_path, notice: "Select your profile to login!"
16      end
```

In the console:

```
NoMethodError (super: no superclass method `authenticate_member!' for #<BrochuresController:0x007fa760e387f8>
Did you mean?  authenticate_sponsor!):

app/controllers/application_controller.rb:13:in `authenticate_member!'
  Rendering /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (3.1ms)
  Rendering /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendering /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (143.0ms)
```

> - My Solution

I don't know what **`super`** refers to but because it was the problem I just change the `authenticate_member!` method in **ApplicationController** in this way:

```
def authenticate_member!
    if !member_signed_in?
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "Select your profile to login!"
    end
end
```

Now everything works fine (or seemed to).

I also have `after_sign_in_path_for` method which I found googling and it seems to work fine.

> - What I want to know is:

1. Do my solutions *(**authenticate_member** and **after_sign_in_path_for**)* are in the right way?
2. Is there another better way to solve this?
3. How can I enable/disable permissions for users in controller actions? - *Some only for Sponsor, some only for Organizer and some for both models*.

BTW: I couldn't find enough info and documentation about `devise_group`, so if someone has a better experience using this feature I would like you to share any kind of docs about it.

Answer (score 0):

Your controllers are all inherited from ApplicationController, so you can easily define authenticate_member! for each controller. 
Example :

```
# organizer_controller.rb
def authenticate_member!
  if !member_signed_in?
    redirect_to organizers_path, notice: "Organizer notice"
  end
end

# sponsor_controller.rb
def authenticate_member!
  if !member_signed_in?
    redirect_to sponsor_root_path, notice: "Notice for sponsors"
  end
end
```